# Typeorm migration:create ignores migrationsDir from the config

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

Based on configuration, I expect migrations to be created inside `migrations` folder in the root  of the project. But no matter what I do `typeorm migration:create -n Test` creates a file in the root folder and not in the `migrations` folder.

At some point I tried passing `-c ormconfig.js` and `--config ormconfig.js` as arguments, but the result is the same.

I also tried changing the folder, and passing the `migration` folder that was created by running `typeorm init` command inside the `src` folder, but it was also ignored.

This is my ormconfig.js configuration:

```js
const { join } = require('path');

require('dotenv-safe').load({
  allowEmptyValues: false,
  path: join(__dirname, '.env'),
  sample: join(__dirname, '.env.example'),
});

module.exports = {
  cli: { migrationsDir: 'migrations' },
  entities: ['./build/entities/*.js'],
  logging: 'all',
  migrations: ['./migrations/*.ts'],
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.POSTGRES_URL,
};
```

And folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into a similar issue - clearly the datasource is working since it's successfully connecting to the DB, but for the life of me I can't get it to output to the correct directory.